# Excel Message Box option. The cell contains formula, so the message box is not showing the result

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the Excel Message Box option. In a cell say E10 I have used a formula, which refers from another sheet. By using this E10 cell, if the cell content changed I want the msg box to appear

This is the code I used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range
Set A = Range("E12:E19")
If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "No" Then
    MsgBox "No Work assigned :( !  " & Target, vbOKOnly, "Abhishek"
    Else
    MsgBox "New task Work on It!  " & Target, vbOKOnly, "Abhishek"
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This code will only fire a message box if the cell being changed is within the range E12:E19 as per the 3rd line of code

Comment: There are to wrong issues in your code. The first one, has been mentioned above and the main problem is **a change in a formula result of a cell does not trigger `Worksheet_Change` event**. The triggered event would be `Calculate` one. But the code should be also adapted. It does not contain a `Target` parameter... Do you "want" he message to appear **only if "E10" cell changes its value by the formula**?

Comment: Yes, actually i dont know the coding language, i am just referring multiple websites. and collaborated the formulas. :) 
Yes, if in E10 the the value changes by the formula then i need message box to appear. In code, i can update the cell range

Comment: Then, copy the code I posted instead of the existing one and play with precedents changing the "E10" value by its formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, copy the next code (instead of existing `Worksheet_Change` event) in the sheet to be processed code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private prevValue As String 'variable to keep the precedent value
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Me.Range("E10")
    If Target.Value <> prevValue Then
        If Target.Value = "No" Then
            MsgBox "No Work assigned :( !  " & Target, vbOKOnly, "Abhishek"
        Else
            MsgBox "New task Work on It!  " & Target, vbOKOnly, "Abhishek"
        End If
        prevValue = Target.Value 'Place the new value in the prevValue variable
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Appreciate it.

Comment: @Abhishek Kulkarni Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...